# Date field not displaying in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I have a date field on my UI using datepicker, it is displaying fine in IE 9, but in IE 10, the date field is not displayed, it does not even display as a text box, just blank and greyed out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: <cfg:datefield name="test.installDate" locked="true"
               disabled="isUpdateEnabled('installDate')"/>

Comment: This is what is in the dateCheck.tag

Comment: <w:datetimepicker name="${name}" label="${derived}" disabled="${disabled}" required="${derivedRequired}"
                      displayFormat="${view.FormatDate}"/>

Comment: I ran the script debugger and below is the error it is displaying in struts_dojo.js                  Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference